# Istio - default ssl certificate to work with Azure Front Door

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

For nginx ingress, there is a way to define default-ssl-certificate with `--default-ssl-certificate` flag.

Ref: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#default-ssl-certificate

How can I do the same for istio?

I have assigned `tls.credentialName` in istio `gateway`. But, it's not the same as nginx-ingress default-ssl-certificate.

**istio_gateway.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
name: SERVICE_GATEWAY
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # Use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      name: SERVICE_NAME-http-80
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "SERVICE_DNS"
  - port:
      name: SERVICE_NAME-https-443
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: SERVICE_CRT
      mode: SIMPLE
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
    hosts:
    - "SERVICE_DNS"
```

VirtualService:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: SERVICE_NAME
spec:
  hosts:
  - SERVICE_DNS
  gateways:
  - SERVICE_GATEWAY
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: SERVICE_PORT
        host: "SERVICE_NAME.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

---

This setup is working for nginx-ingress: https://ssbkang.com/2020/08/17/end-to-end-tls-for-azure-front-door-and-azure-kubernetes-service/
I want to do the same thing with istio.

Comment: How do you issue the certificate? cert-manager or something else? The secret with the TLS will match the certificate name and will be added to the same namespace as the certificate so you can use it with the gateway or the ingress

Comment: @iTech I issued the certificate using cert-manager (letsencrypt). It's working fine if I don't use Azure Front Door. But, Azure Front Door requires some additional configs on the level of `nginx-ingress`. Here is one article I found for nginx ingress https://ssbkang.com/2020/08/17/end-to-end-tls-for-azure-front-door-and-azure-kubernetes-service/ I don't know how to do the same thing on istio.

Comment: Did you configure your gateway with the TLS certificate name generate by cert-manager? Can you share your gateway yaml file?

Comment: @iTech I have updated the question with gateway yaml.

Comment: Under `tls` of the `https` route try to add `privateKey: sds` then `serverCertificate: sds`. Also you can force https redirect by adding `httpRedirect: true` under `tls` key of the http route

Comment: Also ensure that the TLS secret must be in the same namespace of the gateway and the let's encrypt certificate certificate

Comment: @iTech I updated the gateway as suggested. Also, secret, certificate, and gateway are in the same namespace. Just to let you know, if I don't use Azure Front Door, everything is working fine and I am able to access the service with valid SSL.

Comment: what `Host` value do you get from AFD? You might need to use `'*'` in the host to match with the request. Also if you di `curl -v ...` to see the entire logs could be useful

Comment: Also you could set `tls` to `mode: PASSTHROUGH` if you do not want to terminate the SSL.

Comment: @iTech Updated gateway `tls` with `mode: PASSTHROUGH`. The hostname is the same as the endpoint I am trying to access (I confirm that this is right because AFD is working with `nginx-ingress`).

Comment: The article diagram shows that ADF sends `null` host header, if that is the case then you need to use `'*'` in both `host` value so it acts as default catch all route similar to ngix

Comment: I cannot set * in hostname. Warning I am getting from Azure portal is: The host header must be a valid fully qualified domain name (FQDN), IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: Traffic routes with

nginx: AFD => nginx-ingress (configured SSL with -default-ssl-certificate) => ingress (configured SSL).

Istio: AFD => ingress-gateway (**something is missing here**) => gateway (configured SSL)

Comment: You put it in the Gateway yaml definition, it os for sure valid, just surround it with single quote, unless you are missing an additional Azure specific annotation to configure the ADF or LB

Comment: There are no extra annotations from AFD / LB. I also opened a support ticket on azure. But, istio is not in their scope of support.

Comment: Opened a ticket on `istio` GitHub as well. https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/29232
Let's see.

Comment: The gateway and the certificate/secret must be in the same nameapace. I see in your bug description you have them in 2 different namespaces.

Comment: @iTech It's like this from the beginning and it's working for other services and also for this service if I access without Azure Front Door.

Comment: This should not work work as the gateway and secret has to be in the same namespace at least this was the case for previous Istio version.

Comment: Is there a `healthz` endpoint exposed for your service and accessible from AFD? Like defined with `VirtualService`

Comment: @iTech I am using istio version `1.7.4`. Maybe they have changed so that secrets can be accessible from all namespaces. `VirtualService` is updated in the question. No `healthz`